Getting Error: No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=arm64 for nextjs dev and build
Trying to run locally my app which is on nextjs app router and getting this

 ⨯ Error: No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=arm64 runtime=node abi=127 uv=1 armv=8 libc=glibc
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/models/user.ts:6:65)
    at (ssr)/./src/models/user.ts (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/app/page.js:646:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/repos/UserRepo.ts:5:73)
    at (ssr)/./src/repos/UserRepo.ts (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/app/page.js:701:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/hooks/useReAuthenticate.tsx:9:76)
    at (ssr)/./src/hooks/useReAuthenticate.tsx (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/app/page.js:591:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/organisms/Layout/AuthLayer.tsx:11:85)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/organisms/Layout/AuthLayer.tsx (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/app/page.js:492:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/app/page.tsx:8:99)
    at (ssr)/./src/app/page.tsx (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/app/page.js:349:1)
    at Object.__webpack_require__ [as require] (/Users/aniketh/Desktop/project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

getting pre-render issue as well while building
Error occurred prerendering page "/add/group". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=115 uv=1 libc=glibc
    at f.path (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:49918)
    at f (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:48541)
    at 8090 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:44155)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 1322 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:45352)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 2118 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:44113)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 602 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:118032)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)

for all files, i have added 'use client' for all page.tsx but still same.
what should be the fix here ?
Is it because of the outdated library ? i am using pouchdb-upsert which was published 3 years ago.
this is my package.json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "jose": "^5.6.3",
    "next": "14.2.5",
    "pouchdb": "^9.0.0",
    "pouchdb-find": "^9.0.0",
    "pouchdb-upsert": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.12",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "zustand": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/pouchdb": "^6.4.2",
    "@types/pouchdb-find": "^7.3.3",
    "@types/pouchdb-upsert": "^2.2.9",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.34",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


I suddenly got this error as well, did you figure out why it happened?

Hey, I couldnt, i tried two things which solved but not an ideal solution. Lazy loaded pages with SSR disable or go back to nextjs12 with page router.

I managed to fix it, but I cannot remember exactly what I did. I think I removed a couple of webpack plugins and ensured that I did not import any Node.js packages that are not accessible in the Edge runtime, into files that do run in the Edge runtime (e.g. middleware and Route Handlers, such as Server Actions, for Next.js).
